# Как решить задачу: "Введите строку произвольной длины и подсчитайте процент вхождения заданного символа в строку" на c#

Tags: c#, массивы, компиляция

Код ниже при компиляции выдаёт тонну ошибок **Unhandled Exception**:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Введите строку произвольной длины:");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Введите символ для того что бы найти процент его вхождения в строку:");
    string sym = Console.ReadLine();
    int length = str.Length;
    char[] strArr = str.ToCharArray();
    char[] symArr = sym.ToCharArray();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(strArr[i] == symArr[int.Parse(sym)])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    double lengthDouble = Convert.ToDouble(length);
    double counterDouble = Convert.ToDouble(counter);
    double prc = (lengthDouble / counterDouble) * 100;
    Console.WriteLine($"Процент вхождения символа {sym} равен {prc}%");
```

Ошибок в самом IDE нету. Unhandled Exception появляется после ввода данных на 4 строке.

Вот и ошибки:

```
    Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct f
    ormat.
       at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCod
    e type)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, Number
    FormatInfo info)
       at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
       at weirdFlexButOk.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\w
    eirdFlexButOk\weirdFlexButOk\Program.cs:line 19
```

В массивах чайник, в интернете нормального ответа не нашел, как можно избавится от всех этих ошибок?

Comment: Ошибка, вероятно, не из-за ввода в 4 строкеб а в 19 строке. Зачем вы пытаетесь получить число (а вводите вероятно не число, а символ). А потом используя это число как индек получить символ из этого ввода? int.Parse(sym) преобразует строку в число. Причем строка должна быть в числовом формате

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея у вас правильная, но в предложенном вами коде есть несколько ошибок/недостатков:

1. Ваш код падает с ошибкой, потому что вы зачем-то пытаетесь преобразовать введенный символ в число в этой строке:

   ```
   if(strArr[i] == symArr[int.Parse(sym)])
   ```
2. Вы неправильно считаете процент входжения. Правильная формула: `Процент вхождения = количество повторений символа / число символов в строке`. У вас же в коде процент вычисляется по-другому. Вам нужно "перевернуть" дробь.
3. Если вам нужно прочитать единственный символ, то вы можете пойти двумя путями:

- прочитать строку `var syms = Console.ReadLine()` и взять первый
  символ из строки `var sym = syms[0]`,
- прочитать один символ с помощью `var sym = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar`

С учетом вышеуказанных недостатков ваш исправленный код будет в итоге выглядеть так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите строку произвольной длины:");
string str = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Введите символ для того что бы найти процент его вхождения в строку:");
char sym = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
Console.WriteLine();

int length = str.Length;
char[] strArr = str.ToCharArray();
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (strArr[i] == sym)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
double lengthDouble = Convert.ToDouble(length);
double counterDouble = Convert.ToDouble(counter);
double prc = (counterDouble / lengthDouble) * 100;
Console.WriteLine($"Процент вхождения символа {sym} равен {prc}%");
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, код я писал ночью, поэтому там было много ошибок. Код рабочий, благодарю.

Comment: Я не знал про свойство KeyChar, поэтому были ошибки.

Comment: @iAmJustProgrammer пожалуйста! Еще маленькое замечание: у строки есть индексатор, поэтому можно было не писать `char[] strArr = str.ToCharArray();`, а в цикле просто перебирать как массив строковую переменную `str[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Решите задачу простой заменой подстроки на пустую.

100 - sourceString.Replace(subString, "").Length/sourceString.Length*100

Comment: Числитель не совсем корректный, при 100% вхождении ваша формула покажет 0

Comment: а так лучше? идея было посчитать. Артем (b-x)/b*100 идея

Comment: Да, так обычно и делают, + проверка что начальная строка не пустая.

Comment: да конечно, у меня было без 100 из-за видения автора процента

Comment: Автору по душе бегать по циклу. что сказать

Comment: Цикл тоже неплохо, асимптотика у обоих вариантов одинаковая все равно.

Comment: Да конечно, в умелых руках спорить не стану.

Comment: А, ну ещё у тебя тут везде целые числа, что по сути будет округлять до целых и даст ответ 0 при делении если есть хотя бы 1 вхождение.

Comment: Да тестировать тоже надо. Автору вон тоже ровно что там целые

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// оптимальная реализация - 0 динамических выделений памяти
int FindCount(RedaOnlySpan<char> input, ReadOnlySpan<char> pattern)
{
    var cnt = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i <= input.Length - pattern.Length; i++)
        if (input.Slice(i, pattern.Length) // выделяем фрагмент
            .Equals(pattern, StringComparision.Ordinal)) // сравниваем с образцом
            cnt++;

    return cnt;
}
void Run()
{
    var str = ...;
    var sym = ...;
    var symCnt = FindCount(str, sym);
    var symPrc = (double)(symCnt * sym.Length) / str.Length;

    Console.Write("Процент вхождения: ");
    Console.WriteLine(symPrc.ToString("P"));
}
```

<sup>Пример</sup>

```
Введите строку произвольной длины:
abc_Abc_123_
Введите символ для того что бы найти процент его вхождения в строку:
abc
Процент вхождения: 25.00 %
```